# Fresh download kali-linux-2020.2a-rpi3-nexmon-64.img.xz chksum mismatch

Tags: security, kali-linux, hashsum

The downloaded file is a different size to that on the Kali website:

https://www.offensive-security.com/kali-linux-arm-images/

Kali Linux RaspberryPi 2 (v1.2), 3 and 4 (64-Bit)   Torrent     2020.2a     2.1G    40d7ceed8f421069b00858ddb0810a47d13c54bab4fb2de6471d91bd8e5daa8d

even downloaded using cable ethernet and a vpn. The checksums don't match either. This is before I do anything like extract, try to burn image etc. The freshly downloaded file is different.

[Note: even if checksums DID match it could still be hacked as per Linux Mint webpage hacking.]

My file
Size:
2243455472 Jun  3 17:36 kali-linux-2020.2a-rpi3-nexmon-64.img.xz

The compressed file img.xz file is 2.2GB instead of 2GB as on the webpage

sha256sum kali-linux-2020.2a-rpi3-nexmon-64.img.xz 
4b1d705d71c4c6e83269208dc08870e4f69426391ea0bd629546dab4f0cbbd54

Webpage sha256sum:
40d7ceed8f421069b00858ddb0810a47d13c54bab4fb2de6471d91bd8e5daa8d

The extracted file using various methods always yields
sha256sum kali-linux-2020.2a-rpi3-nexmon-64.img
48604ea36e13f0e156a3bbcc894f2e2ab6f53dc22f449d2a7cc11eb1aaac7c59

Webpage sha256sum 
40d7ceed8f421069b00858ddb0810a47d13c54bab4fb2de6471d91bd8e5daa8d

File size:
14000000000 Jun  3 17:55 kali-linux-2020.2a-rpi3-nexmon-64.img
Odd that the file size is exactly 14GB?

What is going on? How can someone be doing a "man in the middle attack"? Could some sort of webpage download diversion be going on?

Anyone else have a similar issue? I have downloaded several times with the same result.

Comment: It's unclear what exactly is happening from your question alone, but I would never disregard a bad checksum on a pen-test tool.

Comment: I've downloaded the same image from their website and got the same `4b1d705d71c4c6e83269208dc08870e4f69426391ea0bd629546dab4f0cbbd54` image you received.  There's a chance it's still just a simple mistake, but better to be on the safe side.  Don't install it and consider [letting them know](https://www.offensive-security.com/contact-us/)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I tried several times to contact them via their webpage and all they would say was what OSSD was I using. That is if it wasn't an automated reply.  The download servers don't have this file - mainly kali .iso files.

Comment: PS. I need to use this image for a course I'm doing.